# Permission Denied Trying to Close window.open in IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, cross-domain, facebook-oauth, permission-denied

I am doing server-side facebook authentication in a popup from my main window. It basically works like this:

1. Click the FB login button Pop open a window using window.open
2. This new window reaches out to my server which tries to authenticate on the back end.
3. If FB redirects, the FB authentication page is displayed in the popup window. At this point, FB is in control.
4. Once the user authenticates, FB redirects back to my server with my provided url.
5. My server responds with some JavaScript, as follows:

   opener.window.location = '/nextPage.html';

   self.close();

In all browser this works great... except for IE (and, not surprisingly, it also works in IE some of the time). In IE I get an error that says "Permission Denied" on the call to opener.window.location.

I realize that IE thinks that this is cross-domain since the window went to facebook for a hot second, but the page that's trying to close the window is from the same domain as the parent. How would I get something like this to work in IE?

Thanks!